# Criteria for 'with Live Tile' sign in Store for Windows Phone Store app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

In Windows Phone Store for Windows Phone 8.1 OS are applications with or without the *with Live Tile* sign under logo in app overview.

[image: example of with Live Tile sign]

Which criteria must the application meet to be detected by Store as it supports Live Tile?

I know that the answer should be obvious – it must support Live Tile, but it is not as simple as it looks like. [My app](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=6314475c-24a2-4a14-9a89-4084006d7b2f) is not detected as it supports Live Tile.

- It calls `PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync`, uploads the `PushNotificationChannel.Uri` to the server and the server sends tile updates via WNS. The tile is regularly updated.
- It contains all scales of all visual assets.

Comment: All I can tell by now is that nobody inside of Microsoft Germany Has an answer to this question. Getting it forwarded, but will probably take some time. I'll bet you updated as soon as I get a reply.

Comment: hmmm... does it depend the technology in use for updating the tiles? http://m.devproconnections.com/windows-8-development/how-use-windows-8-live-tiles-application tells the way tile updates are made with specific TileUpdateManager class in WP8.1 APIs. Considering this link ( http://wmpoweruser.com/apps-with-live-tiles-will-now-be-highlighted-in-the-windows-phone-8-store/ ) they maybe want the specific Live Tile management functionality to be used.

Comment: It seems like you are missing something in Visual Studio. I suggest you to compare your settings with [this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/simple-live-tiles-575b1d66)

Comment: When push notifications are disabled I update application tile exactly like in that sample.

Answer (score 1):

Contacted MSFT Support:

> There is no explicit check. The flag is set during manual instigation
>   of the app in the publishing process.

As the app submission has been changed to publish your app immediately, this flag will only come up once your app is manually checked. That usually only happens some days after your app is published and only in rare cases for updates (or when somebody complains about your app).

Also: The tester has to notice that there is a live tile. If it comes through push or there is no data at the moment of testing or it requires a specific setup, that will just not be visible.

I recommend hinting your live tile in the **certification notes** field (under *describe your package*) to make sure the tester is informed that you have a live tile option.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the Store show the *with Live Tile* tag for Silverlight (XAP) apps but not for Store (Runtime) apps.